# How can i hide navbar in log in & sign up page using authentication location in react.js

Tags: reactjs, navbar, hide, show-hide

Here I have tried with use Location its hide but the navbar is not showing after log in and signup

```
return (
    <div className="App background-Color">
    
    {
        location.pathname === '/LogIn' && location.pathname === '/patientSignUp' && <Navbar/>
    }
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

Because of your logic is wrong. If we called **location.pathname === '/LogIn'** is A,
**location.pathname === '/patientSignUp'** is  B.
So we have three case:

1. You are in /login: A must be **true**, B must  be **false** => A && B = **false** => hide the NavBar
2. You are in /patientSignUp: A must be **false**, B must  be **true** => A && B = **false** => hide the NavBar
3. You are logged in or sign up: A must be **false**, B must  be **false** => A && B = **false** => hide the NavBar

Here are 2 solutions:

1. You can have 2 layouts, in authentication modules, you use Blank Layout and when you all done, use Layout have NavBar. You can use react-router-dom v6 to make it.
2. Changing the logic: 
   {
   location.pathname === '/LogIn' ? null : location.pathname === '/patientSignUp' ? null : < NavBar/>
   }

Comment: Finally I got the answers, Its super simple and easy 

import { useAuthState } from 'react-firebase-hooks/auth';
import auth from './firebase.init';

function App() {
  const [user, loading, error] = useAuthState (auth);

  return (
    <div className="App background-Color">
  
   {
    user && <Navbar/>
   }